# Cascading Comboboxes WPF mvvm and EF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm trying to create cascading comboboxes on my view. I have a table, imported from sql with ADO.NET Entity Data Model:

```
Partial Public Class tbl_Activities
Public Property MRU As String
Public Property Market As String
Public Property Tower As String
Public Property FirstActivity As String
Public Property SecondActivity As String
```

First combobox should contain FirstActivity items and the second one SecondActivity items related to the first one.

I'm using method to populate the first one:

```
    Public Sub FillFirstActivity()
    Using context As New TimerConn
        Dim result = (From act In context.tbl_Activities Where (act.MRU = MRU() And act.Market = MAR() And act.Tower = TOW()) Order By act.FirstActivity).Distinct().ToList()
            For Each act In result
                _First.Add(act)
            Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Properties:

```
    Public Property First() As ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Activities)
    Get
        Return _First
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Activities))
        _First = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Second() As ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Activities)
    Get
        Return _Second
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Activities))
        _Second = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SelectedFirst() As tbl_Activities
    Get
        Return _selectedFirst
    End Get
    Set(value As tbl_Activities)
        _selectedFirst = value
        Me.Second.Clear()
        Me.Second.Add(_selectedFirst)
    End Set
End Property
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeViewM.First}" SelectedIndex="{Binding EmployeeViewM.SelectedFirst}" DisplayMemberPath="FirstActivity"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeViewM.Second}" DisplayMemberPath="SecondActivity"/>
```

**My problem**

I'm not able to populate it correctly. In the first combobox I have doubles (Test1, Test2, Test2), and in the second combobox I get only item related to the item chosen from the first combobox:
[image]

First one should be distinct and the second one with all items for the current activity.

First Combobox = 'Test1', 'Test2'

Second Combobox = If 'Test1' then 'Test1Add', If 'Test2' then 'Test2Add', 'Test2Add1'

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Maybe I should split it into Two tables with PK - FK and then try? If so, how can I bind it to the comboboxes?

My Table view:

[image]

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Comment: Can you go into a little more depth on exactly what you are trying to achieve here? You said *"in the second combobox I get only item related to the item chosen from the first combobox"*, which seems fine, but then you go onto say: *"First one should be distinct and the second one with all items for the current activity."*. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Apologize, I wrote it wrongly. When I pick item from the first combo box 'Test2' I want to have all items connected to that item in the second combo box ('Test2add','Test2add1') and what I get for now is only 'Test2add'. I can add to my question table view, if it help. Thank you.